# Error con XAMPP Navagador en blanco

Tags: apache, xampp

porque me esta pasando esto no me cargan las ventanas ya mire a y todo "corre bien" si alguen tuvu ese error digame si Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál error? No se ve ninguno.

Comment: no carga el contenido ni el phpmyadmin

Comment: Tenes instalada alguna otra herramienta como WAMP o AppServ?

Comment: Busca tu carpeta htdocs/ verifica el index que te esta corriendo

Comment: Hola Shareiv, ¿al final has resuelto el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo tuve un error parecido y era porque no había instalado xampp en la carpeta raíz. Es importante que descomprimas la carpeta de instalación en el directorio raíz de la unidad que vayas usar. No importa la unidad, pero si que sea en la raíz de la unidad.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: no e tenido tiempo estaba de viaje Ahora lo hago

Comment: SI ME FUNCIONO GRACIAS AMIGO

Comment: Perfecto!!! Me alegra que lo solucionases.